# Nivo Banner hyperlink dont work

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. 
I`m using nivo banner for a website. it slides great but when i try a href on the pictures or text it wont work. someon has a fix for this?

CODE HTML:

```
                <div class="slider">
               <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

                  <div class="nivo-main-image">  <a href="http://www.domain.nl/producten/blue"><img src="skins/bootstrap/media/img/slider_1.png" /></a></div>
                  <div class="nivo-main-image">  <a href="http://www.domain.nl/producten/blue"><img src="skins/bootstrap/media/img/slider_2.png" /></a></div>
                  <div class="nivo-main-image">  <a href="http://www.domain.nl/producten/blue"><img src="skins/bootstrap/media/img/slider_3.png" /></a></div>
                  <div class="nivo-main-image">  <a href="http://www.domain.nl/producten/blue"><img src="skins/bootstrap/media/img/slider_4.png" /></a></div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
     /*
 * jQuery Nivo Slider v3.2
 * http://nivo.dev7studios.com
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
      /* The Nivo Slider styles */
      .nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
       .nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    max-width: none;
}
.nivo-main-image {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important; 
    width: 100% !important;
}

/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index: 6;
    display:none;
    background:white; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
    opacity:0;
}
/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nivo-box img { display:block; }

/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    z-index:8;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=8);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0px;
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
        }
```

I hope someon can help me! Thanks guys.

Comment: What does not work? If you cannot click, use developer tools to see if a div is covering the links

Comment: yeah i did, but there is a small div on top of the page where all the links will dropped. Very weird.